# Usage of word mention

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to construct a sentence with the word 'mention' as given below ? Secondly here does the word 'mention' use as a verb?

> There is a specific mention regarding the fundamental rights in chapter 2 of the constitution.

Comment: Probably better like this "There is a specific mention **of** the fundamental rights ..."

Comment: When you consulted your English language dictionary, what did it tell you about the noun _mention_ and the verb _mention_? What did you not understand about the example sentences?

Comment: Depends what you want to say. Can you include what you want the meaning to be?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is perfectly fine. As you can see from this Cambridge Dictionaries Online entry, "mention" can be used as a noun (as well as a verb):

> **[mention](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mention)** *noun*
>
> 1. a short remark or written statement
> 2. **an occasion when something or someone is mentioned**
> 3. an occasion when a person is publicly praised for having done something, such as their job, extremely well